# ASP.NET compiler can't find any namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

I have a `foo.cs` file

```
namespace LoL
{
    public class testing2
    {

    }
}
```

and in

`Default.aspx.cs` file:

**UPDATE:** I don't know if it can help really, but here's all `Default.aspx.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using LoL;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and I get:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'LoL'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

For any class that I try to use. Not libraries only. I tried several solutions moving/copying files, on VS: Porject > add existing file > foo.cs etc

but no luck in any of them.

How to fix this? I have no idea how to fix this.

NOTE: If I try by using F5 mode in VS, it work, but put the website on `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` give this error as in the host.

**EDIT:** By error message on ASP.NET page I can see that IIS is calling C# compiler 4.0, but I'm targeting .NET framework 3.5 on my VS 08 (the last version avaliable on VS 08). Can this have some relation to my problem?

**EDIT2:** I'm able to compile my web site project from command line sucessfully. With `msbuild` program on project path. It just doesn't work when IIS try to compile it. The IIS don't know about `foo.cs` file.

**EDIT3:** Now I'm using `aspnet_compiler`(in cmd.exe) program:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v webApplication4

On path: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webApplication4`

I'm getting same error. So, I looked at Visual Studio configuration stuff, it's the `.csproj` file, I was looking for the inclued files passed by compiler (generated by VS).

I found them on `ItemGroup` tag:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="foo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
```

As your can seen, the `foo.cs` is included to be compiled. So, the file is there. Why aspnet compiler can't  find any namespace?

Comment: You've said it works locally, so what version of IIS are you using when you deploy to your web server? Are you creating a new web site for this? Can you try to give more details about your deployment environment in general? Thanks.

Comment: When you put the website in the inetpub directory, are you copying the source, or are you publishing first? Since it works locally, it kind of seems like your compiled code files aren't making it to the webserver.

Comment: I said it works by using F5 mode in VS... I'm using IIS 7, with VS set target .NET to 3.5. What details do you want? I don't know much about this stuff because I'm not a web dev, I'm a desktop one, trying to edit some pages.

Comment: You may need to change your IIS App Pool to use .NET Framework 2.0... 3.5 is an extension of 2.0. You'll [sometimes] run into config issues trying to run a 2.0/3.5 site in 4.0.

Comment: @AuriRahimzadeh: I've already tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created a webSite and not a webApplication you need to put your `.cs` files in the special `~/App_Code` folder and deploy them on the server. Please read about the differences between a website and a precompiled web application on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx.

Comment: A web application is pre-compiled and you could place the source files wherever you want in the project. They will be compiled and you don't need to deploy them, only the binaries are required. But if this .cs file is in the same web application, it should just work.

Comment: This isn't working for me even in new project created from scratch in VS. I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is LoL in a different project than your website? If so, you need to add a reference to that project in your website project.  In the website, right click on the References folder and click "Add References" and try building again.

If that doesn't work, your LoL project might not be set to build.  Verify in the build output that it is building successfully.  If it isn't, you need to look at your build configurations and verify for your currently active configuration that it is set to build.

Comment: Isn't different, I created it in same solution. "project might not be set to build." You mean "Build Action"? it is set to "Compile".

Comment: Hm. In that case... Look at Darin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy your compiled class libraries in the GAC, using gacutil.exe. Open VS command prompt then type  :

gacutil.exe -i "assemblypath.dll"

Comment: That's a terrible idea. You don't want to register classes in the GAC just because you're having what's probably a simple compilation issue :)

Comment: @AuriRahimzadeh I don't see the problem by doing that, most of the web applications I've been working on always had their code registered in the GAC. Why is this such a bad practice?

Comment: @Jack Yes there is, Visual Studio Tool => Visual Studio Command Prompt

Answer (score 1):

@Machinegon Because of deployment, and for management purposes. Unless it's classes multiple sites use on the server, there's no reason to deploy a web site's DLLs to GAC. Even if used by multiple sites, it's best to have the version the site's known to be compatible with in its bin folder, otherwise registering new versions could break other sites/applications.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but it is a common problem. Please note the following.
You cannot have more than one bin directory in your website. The bin directory must live in the root folder of your website. You cannot have subdirectories that contain bin directories. Often times people will create a webpage in Visual Studio using a new project and then they will publish that webpage to a subdirectory of their website. When the webpages published, a new bin folder will be placed in that subdirectory. That bin directory is useless and will not be referenced by anything. The webpage in the subfolder, will attempt to look for any dependencies in the bin directory that is located in the root of the website.
This is likely something set up by the service provider, or it may simply be the default behavior of IIS/ASP.net. In any event when you publish a website you must publish the entire site. That means everything. The publication process must include everything from the root directory on out. If you add a dependency to a webpage that is in a subfolder, the dependency must be added to the website, the entire website at root folder.